# How to add superscript text to an HTML input box by pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, superscript

I am making a question where people have to input answers that have normal text and superscripts in them. I figure the best way to do this would be to make a button that would enable users to put text in a superscript and then escape the superscript but I have no idea how to go about this and have the text show as a superscript.

This is what I have so far:

```js
function ButtonClick_Test()
{
    document.getElementById("result").value = ' 1s<sup>2</sup>';
}
```

```html
<form>
    Click Here:<br/>
    <input type="button" value="Click Here" name="no" onclick="ButtonClick_Test()">
    <input type="text" id="result" size="20" value="a">
</form>
```

The issues are that it overwrites the content in the input each time and I can't get anything in the superscript.

Comment: We can tell you what's wrong with your code, provided you show it.

Comment: Questions without any practical efforts are generally considered spams and they are likely to receive downvotes.

Comment: An `<input>` field can not display `<sup>` content. It is for plain text input only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input>` field can not display HTML styled content. It supports pure plain text values only. But something you could do. Instead of `input` tag you can use `div` tag with `contenteditable` atribute like follows:

```js
function ButtonClick_Test()
{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ' 1s<sup>2</sup>';
}
```

```css
#result
{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px
}
```

```html
<div id="result" contenteditable="true"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click Here" name="no" onclick="ButtonClick_Test()">
```

Comment: You really should be using something like `<label>` for this.